# Посчитать количество div на странице и вывести это число

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor

Есть сайт на WordPress. На нём есть страница с отзывами пользователя.
Хочу посчитать количество отзывов у этого пользователя и вывести на этой же странице.
У каждого отзыва `<div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно посчитать div с таким классом с помощью JS и вывести это число на странице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить количество таких блоков вот выборка:

```
const count = document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-container.elementor-column-gap-default').length
```

Однако такой способ является весьма костыльным. Для отображения подобных данных лучше делать выборку из БД на стороне бэкэнда и отправлять на клиент уже готовое значение.

UPD:
Могу предложить следующий вариант для отображения этого числа на странице - средствами WordPress в разметку добавьте блок, расположите его так, как вам нужно его отобразить, при этом задав ему аттрибут id, например `id='comments-count'`. После этого уже из любого скрипта на странице можно манипулировать содержимым этого блока, можно отобразить значение так:

```
const countBlockEmelent = document.querySelector('#comments-count');
countBlockEmelent.textContent=  count;
```

Comment: В БД, к сожалению, данная информация хаотична, поэтому хочу попробовать этот способ.
Еще подскажите пожалуйста, как мне теперь это число отобразить на этой странице.

Comment: @TILL, с тем, как отобразить, к сожалению, с трудом помогу хорошим ответом, потому что WordPress'а касался весьма мало. Но некую подсказку оставлю в дополнении к ответу.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас попробую

Comment: Что делаю не так?
Код JS:
<script type="text/javascript">
 
const count = document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-container.elementor-column-gap-default').length;

const countBlockEmelent = document.querySelector('#res');
countBlockEmelent.textContent = count; 
 
</script>

Код html:
<div class="res" id="res" ></div>

При этом, ответ пустой...

Comment: Для начала можно проверить какие ошибки в консоли вывалились. Также, хорошо бы проверить наличие всех необходимых блоков в разметке страницы. Ну и в консоли этот скрипт попытаться выполнить и посмотреть, выполняется ли или ругается на что-то. Также как вариант, проверить, выполняется ли скрипт до того как разметка создаст нужные элементы или после.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Проблема была в том, что JS исполнялся до того, как разметка создавала нужные блоки